# Angular - where to import material items

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to use material items like slider and tooltip. How and where exactly do I import those items, because I keep getting errors that the module cannot be resolved.

I have tried placing the following at the top of app.module.ts as well as the modules of the specific components and the component files.

import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';

I then add the module to the imports, but no matter what combination that I use or where I place the import, I always get an error along the lines of ...

ERROR in node_modules/@angular/material/slider/slider-module.d.ts:8:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of (My Module), but could not be resolved to an NgModule class

Examples on [stack blitz](https://stackblitz.com/angular/madglejpggj?file=src%2Fmain.ts) have different methods.

Comment: You should import the material modules from your feature modules

Comment: Its working in stackblitz. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The stackblitz example, was not what I am writing. That was just an example of a different method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import on app.module.ts and register module on import[]

ex- import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
then 
import[
MatAutocompleteModule
]

Comment: That is the standard method, however it isn't working for me.